# Performance of passing a rvalue parameter as reference

Tags: c++, parameters, rvalue-reference

See simple code below. I'd expect "#3" and "#4" to have the same performance.

"#3" creates the string, assigns it to the variable (lvalue) and then passes it by reference (&).
"#4" creates the string (rvalue) and passes it by reference (&&).

However, "#4" is about 5 times slower. As slow as "#1" and "#2". Why is this?

"#1": Function with byvalue lvalue parameter is called.
Speed: 2715

"#2": Function with byvalue rvalue parameter is called.
Speed: 2647

"#3": Function with l-value reference parameter is called.
Speed: 566

"#4": Function with r-value reference parameter is called.
Speed: 2638

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <time.h>
#include <exception>

void MyFunctionByValue(std::wstring text)
{
    text += L".";
}
void MyFunction(std::wstring& text)
{
    text += L".";
}
void MyFunction(std::wstring&& text)
{
    text += L".";
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int uint_LoopSize = 1000000;
    long lng_Start;
    std::wstring text = L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_";

    std::wcout << L"#1: Function with byvalue lvalue parameter is called." << std::endl;
    lng_Start = clock();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < uint_LoopSize; i++)
    {
        text = L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_";
        MyFunctionByValue(text);
    }
    std::wcout << L"Speed: " << clock() - lng_Start << std::endl;
    std::wcout << std::endl;

    std::wcout << L"#2: Function with byvalue rvalue parameter is called." << std::endl;
    lng_Start = clock();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < uint_LoopSize; i++)
    {
        MyFunctionByValue(L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_");
    }
    std::wcout << L"Speed: " << clock() - lng_Start << std::endl;
    std::wcout << std::endl;

    std::wcout << L"#3: Function with l-value reference parameter is called." << std::endl;
    lng_Start = clock();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < uint_LoopSize; i++)
    {
        text = L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_";
        MyFunction(text);
    }
    std::wcout << L"Speed: " << clock() - lng_Start << std::endl;
    std::wcout << std::endl;

    std::wcout << L"#4: Function with r-value reference parameter is called." << std::endl;
    lng_Start = clock();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < uint_LoopSize; i++)
    {
        MyFunction(L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_");
    }
    std::wcout << L"Speed: " << clock() - lng_Start << std::endl;
    std::wcout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you compiled this with optimisations turned on, then likely you are not testing what you expect.

Comment: #1, #2 and #4 keep allocating and freeing memory. #3 reuses storage allocated once, and managed by `text` variable. I expect this accounts for all performance difference.

Comment: Ah ok that would make sense. I thought 'text = string literal' would force an allocation. Thanks.